# How to apply query to model if field not filtered

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a range of modules running on generator.yml. In some of those I would like to hide records by default of Status: CLOSED (being the last of a range of Statuses). OF course if the user filters for CLOSED i want to show these records.

I thought it would make sense to apply andWhere('status_id=?',Status::CLOSED) in a specific table_method , but how do I access the filters of the module from within the model?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a new field e.g. 'showClosedStatus' (you ll need to add the widget and validator in the form)
then add getFilterDefaults() in the generatorconfiguration with

public function getFilterDefaults() {
    return array('showClosedStatus' => 'false');
}

then add the 
function addShowClosedStatusColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $q, $field, $value){
if($value == false){
$q->andWhere('status!=closed')
}

Comment: I'll use this as a workaround - it only works if the Default is true, otherwise addShowClosedStatusCOlumnQuery is not reached. I would prefer it worked with a single field, but this is good enough for now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do? Is it to default the state of one of the filters?

If so, that is fairly easily done. apps//modules//lib/GeneratorConfiguration.php add a method to the class called "getFilterDefaults":

```
class modulenameGeneratorConfiguration extends BaseModulenameGeneratorConfiguration
{
  public function getFilterDefaults() {
    return array('status' => 'something');
  }

}
```

Only difference for you is that it sounds like you can filter on an array of values for the field in question. Never had cause to try this, but I'd imagine returning an array of values  in place of something would be the way to do that.

Comment: No, I need to apply the query != CLOSED to the filter, unless the chosen filter is =CLOSED

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer, based on the comment from OP.

If you want to adjust how the query is constructed for a given field, find the relevant filter form in lib/filter/doctrine and add a method like this to it:

```
public function addStatusColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $q, $field, $value) {
  // do whatever you want here - ie: check $value, and add the query conditions you need to $q.

  return $q;
}
```

Comment: looks very close to what I want, problem is this function is not called if no filter is selected - I still need to filter then though. Any documentation of the flow I could look at?

Comment: I also found this http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/whats-new#chapter_a2fae23c9403b0e9ec99806fccf6b53e_sub_sfformfilterdoctrine but unclear where to put the filter seed. Changing in table_method leaves me with the same problem